# Java SSLServerSocket soTimeout not working?

Tags: java, ssl, thrift

I'm using Apache Thrift server written on Java. When i'm create ServerSocket i'm pass a parameter called clientTimeout with value 60000 (ten minutes). But this not work as expected - i'm connect to server, execute a method wait 11 minutes execute method again without reconnect and didn't get error (as i'm expected).
I'm try do it on not SSL thrift server, this work fine.
In thrift sources i'm found how to SSL socket created, seems ok.

```
   private static TServerSocket createServer(SSLServerSocketFactory factory, int port, int timeout, boolean clientAuth,
                                    InetAddress ifAddress, TSSLTransportParameters params) throws TTransportException {
    try {
      SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(port, 100, ifAddress);
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
      serverSocket.setNeedClientAuth(clientAuth);
      if (params != null && params.cipherSuites != null) {
        serverSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(params.cipherSuites);
      }
      return new TServerSocket(serverSocket);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new TTransportException("Could not bind to port " + port, e);
    }
  }
```

has anyone such problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout on a `ServerSocket` affects `ServerSocket.accept()` only.It is not inherited by accepted `Sockets` as a read timeout. If you want that, you have to set it explicitly. This is a difference between the Java API and the BSD Sockets API.

Comment: May me i'm don't understand you correctly... Proble is not about read timeout of client. Problem is about server doesn't close opened connection after ten minutes of client idle. I'm think server don't close they at all. But you say setSoTimeout is only about .accept() and i'm need find other timeouts in accepted socet instead?

Comment: @AlexeySviridov I said `ServerSocket.setSoTimeout()` is an accept() timeout. Socket.setSoTimeout() is a read timeout. If you want a read timeout on accepted sockets, that's the API you need to call,and you need to call it on the accepted socket.

Comment: Actually this is a bug in thrift server code, but you give right direction. I'm fix thrift server code and create a bug in thrift jira - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1523. There i'm explain this bug as i can, with my ugly english :) Please coorect your answer (add info from thrift bug if you can understand what i'm wrote) and i'm mark it as right.

Comment: @AlexeySviridov My answer is correct regardless of what the Thrift server does.

Comment: Answer absolutely correct, but not completely answer to question. If anyone else meet this problem in thrift,your answer will not solve this problem. But ok, this was great for me, and i'm mark it as right.

Comment: @AlexeySviridov In what way does 'you have to set it explicitly' not answer the question?

Comment: Source question about thrift SSL server behavior, your answer about plain java SSL server behavior. Your answer help me, but not directly answer to source question

Comment: @AlexeySviridov The timeout you are expecting to be inherited from the ServerSocket is not being inherited by the accepted socket. Otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question. The behaviour of SSLServerSocket is the same whatever kind of server you pile on top of it. Your comments notwithstanding. If you set the timeout on the accepted socket it will work. If you have any actual information to add, by all means do so.

Comment: Real answer IMHO must be 'This is bug in apache thrift SSL server implementation. Its affects all versions prior 0.9 wait for 0.9 release or use svn trunk version right now'. 0.9 - version where was my patch applyed. My patch was inspired by your answer.

Comment: @AlexeySviridov This is now getting quite ridiculous. I had to ask you three separate times what is wrong with my answer, and this is the best you can come up with. The answer is the one I gave you. You are just wasting everybody's time with this nonsense when you should be thanking me for providing the correct answer and solution. *Applying* the solution, i.e. in this case patching the Apache Thrift server, is strictly up to you.